# angular2 - Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Tags: angular, auth0

Trying update angular2 was a total disaster along with the the cli.  I tried to revert but cant with regards to the angular2-cli.  Now my app will not load because of JWT with auth0.  It used to work.  Error is below.

```
209:29 is this line:
   tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
```

But it used to work and it part of the docs for auth0:
   https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#basic-configuration

```
   'ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 209:29 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/angular2cliisstupid/Documents/frontend/qta/src/app/app.module.ts`
provideAuth({
              headerName: 'Authorization',
              headerPrefix: 'bearer',
              tokenName: 'token',
              tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
              globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
              noJwtError: true
          })
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `localStorage.getItem('id_token')`?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and this solved the problem:

1. Define your Authorization module like this:

`@NgModule({
         providers: [
            {
              provide: AuthHttp,
              useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
              deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
            }
          ]
        })
export class AuthorizationModule { }`

2. Export authHttpServiceFactory function somewhere in the same file

   `export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
     return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
           tokenName: 'token',
           tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
           globalHeaders: [{'Content-Type':'application/json'}],
           headerName: 'Authorization',
           headerPrefix: 'JWT',
           noJwtError: true
       }), http, options);
   }`

Comment: Thank you! `export function authHttpServiceFactory`  <- was just missing the `export` there and spent hours looking for the cause.

Comment: I am glad it helped you.